# Phonegap getPicture method fails when image file names with spaces in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using the latest version of the phonegap camera plugin (i.e. 0.2.9) and 3.5 of phonegap Build, testing on Android, below is my code for getting images:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
       function(message) { console.log('get picture failed');alert(message) },
                         { quality: 50, targetWidth: 400, targetHeight: 400,
                           destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                           sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
);
```

when i choose an image where its filename without spaces (e.g. test.jpg), the uploadPhoto method is called successfully, but when i choose an image where its filename with space (test 2.jpg), error occurs with the alert message "Unable to create bitmap".

Comment: I think you need to **URLEncode** your filename for it to work, Since spaces are not accepted as per URL standard specification.

Comment: but which part to encode?  i tried destinationType: encodeURI(navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI), still not working @frank

Comment: you need to encode the filename (strings containing spaces).

Comment: Maybe share the uploadPhoto function since that is what is throwing the error.

Comment: but the problem is 'uploadPhoto' is not get called, it's only called when getPicture successfully, now it occurs error - console.log('get picture failed');alert(message), and the alerted message is "Unable to create bitmap" @RaymondCamden

Comment: hence i have no idea where to encode the filename since the 'uploadPhoto' is never get called when it throws errors @frank

Comment: @VeniceLeung Hi Venice, were you able to resolve this? I am getting exactly the same issue, seems to be a bug in phonegap/cordova. Thanks!

Comment: i am facing the same problem, did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to update to the latest version (5.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Use *JavaScript encodeURI() Function* to encode the path.

This will give you the file path in a format accepted by the standard specification. Still '(' and ')', which appears commonly on file names, are not handled by the function.

However, tailing the encodeURI function with 2 *JavaScript String replace() Method* to replace them with their RAW URL encoding equivalents should solve the issue.

```js
var success = function(path) {
  var urlEncodedPath = encodeURI(path)
    .replace('(', '%28')
    .replace(')', '%29');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = urlEncodedPath;
  // do something
};

// Actual success callback from cordova camera
// navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, options);

// An Example for demonstating in browser
success('file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.your.app/cache/hd wallpaper nature(1).jpg');
```

```html
<p id="demo" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></p>
```