# Phonegap camera getPicture fails in Android when the image filename contains spaces

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My version of the phonegap camera plugin is 0.3.4 and phonegap cli of 4.1.2-0.22.10, android phonegap platform version is 3.6.4, build version 3.5.0 in config.xml, testing on Android 4.x, below is my code snippet for getting images from Samsung phone from either gallery or dropbox:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
uploadPhoto,
function(message)
{
  console.log("Get Picture Failed:"+ message);
}
,
{
  quality: 50,
  allowEdit:false,
  correctOrientation: true,
  targetWidth: 800,
  destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
  sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
);
```

when i choose an image from the gallery it always takes the native_uri (content:// )rather than the file_uri (FILE:///), irrespective of the destination type chosen. But when the app tries to access an image via dropbox the returned uri is always file_uri irrespective of the destination type chosen. Now,

- If the filename does not have a space in it like 'Photo7.jpg' then it
  works fine for all cases.
- If the file name does have space in it like 'Photo 7
  new.jpg' then it works fine if it resides in the gallery since the native_uri is always used and it eliminates the space. Please note that the file_uri still contains space in the filename but is not being used by the getpicture method.
- Now the issue comes in when the app tries to access the same image 'Photo 7
  new.jpg' via dropbox. In this case the returned uri is always file_uri and contains spaces. This fails the getpicture method of the camera api and executes failure callback with message "Get Picture Failed:Unable to create bitmap!"

Is there any way to accomodate space by tweaking phonegap/cordova code? Else is there any workaround to encode_uri or anything else?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a URI: have you tried encoding the spaces to `%20` or `+`?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc! but in the case of phonegap camera api, the URI is thrown out by the getpicture method only if it is successful (the magic happens in the native code that resides within getpicture()). If getpicture() fails i dont get to modify the uri, i only get the error msg. So unless i touch the native code within phonegap api i wont be able to encode the uri. That is where i need help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the url with JS encodeURI function.
For detailed answer look at the below answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249021/6778969